# iPad app not scaling properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, xcode-storyboard

I am new to iOS development. Coming from Visual Studio and C#, XCode is very confusing to use.

I followed Ray Wenderlich's tutorial here to make my first app. The app works fine but the app does not scale to the full screen even though I've designed the UI such in XCode Storyboard. It currently looks like this:

[image: iPad app not aligned to full screen.]

As you can notice, the alignment is not proper. In XCode though, I've placed the controls properly:

[image: XCode Storyboard view]

How do I fix this?

**Note:** I'm testing in an iPad Air.

Comment: You just not give any constraints..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a VS developer, I can completely relate with you.

In the Xcode world, you must use constraints, to explain to the iOS device how to position your controls, relative to the size of the screen.

I'd recommend going back to RayWenderlich and have a read of this:
[AutoLayout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

It *will* drive you mad... but once you understand it, it'll allow you to do your control positioning without writing any code.

Just remember that you need to add enough constraints to *each* control so XCode can exactly work out the width & height, x-pos and y-pos.

(It takes some practice.  And patience.  And swearing.  Mostly swearing.)

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I'll follow your suggestion. :)

Comment: I figured it out from the link you shared. Thanks @Mike.